# c-media / gigaware usb headset driver

Tags: windows-7, usb, headset

I have a USB headset (made by Gigaware) which has been working fine for years in my Win 7 machine. But now the device shows up as 'C-media USB headset' in the 'unknown' devices part of Device Manager with no drivers and any automatic search is unable to find the drivers. Note, the driver always listed as 'C-media USB Headset'.

My hunch is that either PNP is not working fully--uninstalling and re-inserting does put the device back into the unknown part. Or driver files are not being found online. I have downloaded software from cmedia.com.tw but those did not work. Also, note I never needed any installation media nor were they supplied.

The headphone is fine--works fine in my Windows 8 Acer W510 tablet.

May be I could delete some registry key and/or some driver dll files to remove some caching to start from scratch but don't know which files to delete?

*** Some more info** On all the USB Ports not only is the headphone is recognized as 'C-media' but also, for some months, my Nokia Lumia 920 is not being recognized as a device--the phone used to. So, perhaps, there is some PnP issue?***

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: 1. Try [USB Oblivion](http://code.google.com/p/usboblivion/). 2. Delete the headset and all USB controllers/hubs from Device Manager, reboot and hopefully it'll get re-detected and reinstalled properly.

Comment: @Karan: No luck. Running to actually 'clean' by using USBOblivion and then restarting did detect and re-install my external USB drive as well as the headphone but the headphone is still having same problems as in my Question above. Thanks.

Comment: Not option 2 yet. Let me see...

Comment: Are you sure I could delete ALL controllers under 'Universal Serial Bus Controllers'? I mean some are like 'Intel 6 Series...'? I don't want to destablize the entire system!?

Comment: alright. I have already backed up registry

Comment: oh, boy, deleting a couple of those controllers made me lose kb and mouse--still can't get to them (on a different computer right now). will reboot..

Comment: I have this computer finally working again after doing a System Restore. The original problem persists though.

Comment: *** I think I have figured out what's happening! Looks like my USB mouse is the culprit. Will post more info soon***

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem: It was the USB mouse in my computer which was the culprit. While the mouse itself worked fine it was disrupting other USB devices to work. Specifically, my Nokia Lumia 920 phone, which was recognized before, stopped being recognized while connected via a micro USB cable. Similarly, the C-media Headphone device started showing as an 'unknown device'.

I replaced the mouse with another USB mouse, and voila!, computer not only recognizes the Lumia 920 (though I had to download some software for that) but also the C-Media headset started showing correctly.

BTW, another user had reported similar problem elsewhere on the web, related to his/her mouse crashing. That gave me the clue.

@Karan: Thanks for your help again.